# WSO2 APIM 3.0.0 install/config problem with Publisher and Store: "invalid_callback - Registered callback does not match with the provided url"

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

After installing version **3.0.0** of the **WSO2 API Manager** I am getting errors trying to access the **Publisher** and the **Store**.

This is the error at the **Store** (https://myhost.my.org:9443/store)

> Error 405 - Method Not Allowed
>   [image]

As for the **Publisher**, the url https://myhost.my.org:9443/publisher redirect to this url...

https://myhost.my.org:9443/authenticationendpoint/oauth2_error.do?oauthErrorCode=invalid_callback&oauthErrorMsg=Registered+callback+does+not+match+with+the+provided+url

...and displays this error message:

> invalid_callback - Registered callback does not match with the provided url

[image: invalid_callback message]

**Notes:**

- I can access the admin page just fine (https://myhost.my.org:9443/carbon)
- I replaced every occurance of '`localhost`' with '`myhost.my.org`' in every file in `.../wso2/wso2am/3.0.0/repository/conf`, including '`carbon.xml`'
- Logs reveal the following: (`.../wso2/wso2am/3.0.0/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log`)

  > WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} Provided Callback URL does not match with the provided one.

**Stack:**

- Ubuntu 18.04
- OpenJDK 11.0.4
- WSO2 API Manager 3.0

**Installation steps followed:**
https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/GettingStarted/quick-start-guide/

**Installation commands:**

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)

sudo wget https://product-dist.wso2.com/downloads/api-manager/3.0.0/downloader/wso2am-linux-installer-x64-3.0.0.deb

sudo apt install ./wso2am-linux-installer-x64-3.0.0.deb

sudo service wso2am-3.0.0 start
```

The installation notes refer to `localhost`/`127.0.0.1`. But I am installing on `myhost.my.org`.

Files manually modified in `.../wso2/wso2am/3.0.0/repository/conf` (replaced '`localhost`' with '`myhost.my.org`' and '`127.0.0.1`' with '`this.is.my.ip`'):

```
api-manager.xml
broker.xml
carbon.xml
datasources.properties
deployment.toml
event-broker.xml
log4j2.properties
messaging-event-broker.xml
metrics.xml
registry.xml
thrift-authentication.xml
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to update the callback URL in the Service Provider.

1) Go to `/carbon` and edit the relevant SP.

[image]

2) Edit the OAuth app in it.

[image]

You will see the callback URL like this.

```
regexp=(https://localhost:9443/publisher/services/auth/callback/login|https://localhost:9443/publisher/services/auth/callback/logout)
```

Update all occurrences of localhost with your hostname.

Save both OAuth app and SP.

Comment: If you are using a distributed setup (separate pub store and key manager), then editing the SP from key manager will get reflected after the cache expiry of publisher and store nodes

Comment: I marked this as the accepted answer because it solved 1 of 2 problems: 
`invalid_callback - Registered callback does not match with the provided url`.

So now I can access both the Admin (carbon) and Publisher.

But the Store is still presenting `Error 405 - Method Not Allowed`.

Comment: As @egalves has answered, it should be `devportal` instead of `store`.

Answer (score 2):

About:

> his is the error at the Store (https://myhost.my.org:9443/store)

Maybe you can find what you need at https://myhost.my.org:9443/devportal

Comment: Ah, very good, thanks @egalves. That solves the problem. It looks like 'store' has been rebranded as 'devportal' in version 3.0

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter the same error with callback URL on devportal, log into Management Console, under list of Service Providers, edit `admin_admin_store` instead.